# Sql server connection with symfony 2 and Propel

Tags: sql-server, symfony, propel

I have installed the propel orm bundle on symfony 2.3 and I have configured it in the app/config/config.yml file like this :

```html
propel:
    dbal:
        default_connection:         symfony
        connections:
            symfony:
                driver:               sqlsrv
                user:                 null
                password:             null
                dsn:       sqlsrv:server=%database_host%;Database=%database_name%
```

I use the "sqlsrv" driver for sql server  , it is correctly installed on my php folder.

My user and password field are null because i use windows authentification. I have checked this configuration with doctrine and it works, i can connect on the database :

```html
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   sqlsrv
        host:     "%database_host%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     null
        password: null
        charset:  UTF8
```

But with propel I can't connect with this configuration , can you help me please ?

( I have checked on console this command : *php app/console propel:database:create* and I have this message *"No database name found"* )

Thanks

Comment: `I can't connect` is not a suitable description of your problem. Without error message we can't help you.